# Stop editor from adding “amp;” after every “&”

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, wp-editor, wysiwyg

The WordPress editor keeps adding “amp;” after every “&”.

This effectively breaks all my custom links. How can i stop this?
I don’t mind all the others things the editor does to the formatting i just need it to stop adding “amp;”. Is there a filter i can use?

Comment: Please check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27401/wordpress-is-converting-to-amp-inbetween-code-brackets

Comment: Sadly his function doesn't work and his other solution involves editing every single post manually which isn't an option when there are thousands of them.

Comment: what do you have against properly formatted html? do you realize that your urls might be totaly broken if there will be a & and not &amp; in them?

Comment: This are Microsoft's Onedrive links and when amp; is added the link redirects to the homepage.

Comment: Then OneDrive is broken and you should complain to them. Bare ampersands are not allowed in HTML.

Comment: does do not make any sense. browsers are supposed to handle the conversion from &amp; to &. They only handle & correctly because they are trying to be forgiving when a badly formed html can be made to make sense

Comment: @Mark Kaplun GET parameters should be `?` and `&` not `&amp;`
@MichaelRogers what else is installed on your website because by default WordPress does not change `&` to `&amp;` in hyperlinks. It does so when you check the "text" version in the editor but in the actual content the `href` is outputted as the correct URL.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow, ha? what does GET parameters have to do with validity of HTML?

Comment: Mark Kaplun he is clearly talking about hyperlinks so the &amp; is only a problem because it's outputted in the href attribute of hyperlinks and & in an href has nothing to do with valid HTML. Also validity is also really not an issue for that matter as all modern browers solve invalidities for you while rendering the page.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow, no, & by itself is simply invalid anywhere in HTML... in text, in attribute, in href, anywhere.

Comment: You're so missing the point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to hook into `wp_insert_post_data` and do some regex magic to replace all instances of `&amp;` with `&`:

```
// when saving posts, replace &amp; with &
function cc_wpse_264548_unamp( $data ) {

    $data['post_content'] = preg_replace(
        "/&amp;/", // find '&amp;'
        "&", // replace with '&'
        $data['post_content'] // target the 'post_content'
    );

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'cc_wpse_264548_unamp', 20 );
```

You will obviously only see changes when a post is saved/updated.

Comment: This would replace `&amp;` not only on links but on the complete content.

Comment: @cjbj You speak the true-true. Michael Let me know if this works and I can adjust the regex so it targets URLs only. =)

Comment: So simple, this does it! Bounty in 12 hours. Not sure why everyone embarks on a philosophical quest to find what is the meaning of life instead of attempt a solution to the problem in question.

Comment: Because you shouldn't have to do anything at all except looking for the problem that shouldn't be in your website to begin with.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow well IT IS. What should i do? email at Bill Gates and wait for him to update his service or find workaround on my end? Sometimes you gotta make things work.

Comment: @MichaelRogers I'm wondering if the actual problem may be double escape of `&`. Can you please provide me with a URL of a onedrive file and I can test this.

Comment: @ChristineCooper `https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AOQ-IED97Mt_bdU&id=CE5A0ED72052CD08%21107&cid=CE5A0ED72052CD08`

Comment: @MichaelRogers well it doesn't matter what onedrive URL i put in my WordPress editor, it never fails to open correctly which is why i'm positive there is a problem at your website and not OneDrive. but if you want to use a filter to prevent a problem from occuring then by all means.

Comment: @MichaelRogers Can you please post a link to a page on your site where the link doesn't work? I'm actually pretty confident that it is a matter of double escaping. You need to turn off this fix I posted so I can replicate your issue.

Comment: To see the issue, you have to paste that link on the visual editor and click "text" mode, that's when the `amp;` gets added.

Comment: @ChristineCooper - in the lastet WP Version it does not work... Any update for Gutenberg? thx

Comment: @NewUser Can you please click the update button, and then *refresh* the page to see if it is working? I believe using Gutenberg, a refresh may be required to see the change on the page.

Comment: @ChristineCooper - i already tried. it does not work unfortuntely.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the TinyMCE Config as i did. I just add entity_encoding = "raw"

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    entity_encoding : "raw"      
});
</script>
```